# Why is my child window unresponsive to mouse events?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I have created a customized static window which displays a bitmap image, this window is the child window of some other window. Now I want to capture mouse events for this window, so that I can provide functionality to crop the image.

But the problem is Mouse events are not passed to this child window....
following is a code snippet of the `WndProc` of child window ..

```
WNDPROC origStatProc;
    // Variable which stores the handle of BITMAP image
HBITMAP hBitmap=NULL;
LRESULT CALLBACK dispWndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HDC hdc;
    static PAINTSTRUCT paintSt;
    static RECT aRect;

    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd,&paintSt);
            GetClientRect(hwnd,&aRect);
            if(hBitmap!=NULL)
            {               
                HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
                if(memDC!=NULL)
                {
                    BITMAP bmp;
                    GetObject(hBitmap,sizeof(bmp),&bmp);
                    SelectObject(memDC,hBitmap);
                    SetStretchBltMode(hdc,HALFTONE);
                    StretchBlt(hdc,0,0,aRect.right,aRect.bottom,
                    memDC,0,0,bmp.bmWidth,bmp.bmHeight,
                    SRCCOPY);
                    DeleteObject(&bmp);
                    ReleaseDC(hwnd,memDC);
                }
            }           
            // the code for painting 
            EndPaint(hwnd,&paintSt);
        }
        break;
        case STM_SETIMAGE:
        {           
            InvalidateRect(hwnd,&aRect,true);           
        }
            break;  
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            {
                int xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
                int yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
                char xstr[10];
                _itoa(xPos,xstr,10);
                MessageBox(NULL,xstr,"X Value ",MB_OK);
            }
            break;

        default:
            return origStatProc(hwnd,msg,wParam,lParam);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what else I need to capture mouse events inside this Child window...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window class that you use for the window will determine certain default behaviors for the window. The Static window class is particularly difficult to work with, because Windows makes assumptions that the window will never change its contents, and won't interact with the user in any way. You'll probably find that the WM_LBUTTONDOWN is being passed to the parent window.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly: static windows declare themselves to be 'invisible' to mouse clicks by returning HTTRANSPARENT in response to WM_NCHITTEST. Because of this, windows passes the mouse click on to the parent. If you want to process the mouse clicks in the statics, you'll need to also override this behavior to return HTCLIENT instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have called DefWndProc() instead of origStatProc(hwnd,msg,wParam,lParam) and the problem is solved....

anyWays thanks to everyone....

Comment: The likely reason that this working is that DefWndProc returns HTCLIENT for the interior of a window by default. But if you're calling DefWndProc() in response to all window messages, you don't really have a custom static anymore; you essentially have a new control - there's nothing left of the original static (other than it's other WNDCLASS values). You may as well create your own window class rather than basing it on static in the first place. Was there any behavior from static that you were planning on preserving?

Comment: @BrendanMck : STM_SETMESSAGE.... I wanted to use this message of static controls..

Comment: The thing about messages is that they are basically just numbers. You can have a custom control that responds to any messages you want - you don't need to be based on any specific control to do so. So, with a custom control, you could create your own STM_SETIMAGE equivalent with a new name and new value - or you can just 'reuse' the existing STM_SETIMAGE value. Windows doesn't care either way, it will still deliver the message to the target window, regardless of whether the target window 'understands' what the message means.